# how to change variable type to accept numbers more than 100 quintillion

Tags: mit-scratch

I am a beginner in scratch and working on a simple program that speaks out numbers in multiples of 10 and the highest number it would speak using text-to-speech tool is 100 quintillion. After this it would start speaking in exponential format.

How can I change the datatype of variable in a way it accepts numbers more than 100 quintillion and wont change it to exponential format?

Comment: I would guess that this is a limitation of the text-to-speech API being used by Scratch. Maybe you could try plugging in the actual word that you want the extension to say? (Something like `say "1 sextillion"` with the extension block.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change the datatype of variable

Well, first of all, you can't change the datatype of a variable in Scratch

> accepts numbers more than 100 quintillion and wont change it to exponential format

The way Scratch works is that it does that and there is no lifehack I could find to fix this, but you could try deep searching the Scratch Forums

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to use a base64 counting system as opposed to base 10, which humans use.

You are currently storing your number in base 10, where you are limited by the numbers 0-9; whenever you use up all of these digits, you must use another character space. However, since scratch doesn't restrict variables to only numbers, we can make use of non-numerical characters too.

[Base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) uses capital A to capital Z, then uses lowercase A to lowercase Z, uses all digits 0-9, then uses the symbols `+` and `/`. Luckily, Scratch supports all of these characters!